# Electronjs : Saving a db file after compilation

Tags: javascript, electron, nedb

So I created a small electronJs desktop application, and for the data storage I used nedb.
In dev mode, it works perfectly fine, but when I compile in production (I'm on mac), I can't write the database file anymore.

Here is the code I use to declare my database and create my file if it doesn't exist already :

```
var Datastore = require('nedb')
, db = new Datastore({ filename: 'datafile.db', autoload: true });
```

So in dev mode, the file is created and everything is okay.
But after compiling, my app doesn't create my "datafile.db"

Someone can help ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev mode the file is where you expect it to be, but most likely, your production code is running from a different file location. So...

This will likely be a path problem. Try to create absolute paths everywhere to ease this pain.  You can use node `__dirname` to help with this.